# Do I need a content provider to stream http video to android.widget.VideoView?

Tags: java, android, scala, android-mediaplayer, android-videoview

I have some odd behavior while trying out Android's VideoView widget. When I set the url programatically (scrapped from the Internet):

```
val url = getURLOnline()
val video = Uri.parse(url)
videoView.setVideoURI(video)
```

I get the following error:

```
MediaPlayer: Couldn't open "http://cdn.samplemediafile.xyz/thevideo.mp4": java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: "http://cdn.samplemediafile.xyz/thevideo.mp4"
NuPlayer: onSetVideoSurface(0xa93b3000, no video decoder)
FileSource: Failed to open file '"http://cdn.samplemediafile.xyz/thevideo.mp4"'. (No such file or directory)
```

Funny thing is, when I hard-code the same URL it suddenly works fine! So, it's not a codec problem. Of course I tried other Videos, too. Same result, only hard-coded works. Why is that?

```
val video = Uri.parse("http://cdn.samplemediafile.xyz/thevideo.mp4")
videoView.setVideoURI(video)
```

Answer (score 0):

Found it! Silly coding mistake...

```
Failed to open file '"http://cdn.samplemediafile.xyz/thevideo.mp4"'
                     ^                                           ^
```

The URL comes back surrounded with quotation marks. Needed a fix in my scraping code. Video is playing fine now.